# How can I modify this deep merge function to support array merging too?

Tags: javascript

I found a recursive object merger function, but it doesn't support array merging, and in the case where duplicate sub-properties exists within the object that are arrays carrying different values, I want those arrays to `concat` rather than overwrite (but all other properties overwrite, like usual).

```js
/**
 * Simple object check.
 * @param item
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isObject(item) {
  return (item && typeof item === 'object' && !Array.isArray(item));
}

/**
 * Deep merge two objects.
 * @param target
 * @param ...sources
 */
function mergeDeep(target, ...sources) {
  if (!sources.length) return target;
  const source = sources.shift();

  if (isObject(target) && isObject(source)) {
    for (const key in source) {
      if (isObject(source[key])) {
        if (!target[key]) Object.assign(target, { [key]: {} });
        mergeDeep(target[key], source[key]);
      } else {
        Object.assign(target, { [key]: source[key] });
      }
    }
  }
  
  else if (Array.isArray(target) && Array.isArray(source)) {
    // I was thinking to modify it this way, but I'm pretty confused with the     
    // recursion here and think this isn't on the right track
    return target.concat(source)
  }

  return mergeDeep(target, ...sources);
}

let foo1 = {
    bar1: {
        "baz1" : true,
        "baz2" : 1,
        "baz3" : [true, 1, "true", false]
    },
    bar2: [
        "baz1",
        "baz2"
    ],
    bar3: true,
    bar4: 1,
    bar5: "true",
    bar6: false,
}

let foo2 = {
    bar1: {
        "boop" : true,
        baz3: ["doodle"]
    },
    bar2: [
        "boop"
    ],
}

let foo3 = mergeDeep(foo1, foo2);

console.log("foo3.bar1.baz3 is equal to [true, 1, 'true', false, 'doodle'] ?", JSON.stringify(foo3.bar1.baz3)==JSON.stringify([true, 1, `true`, false, 'doodle'])) 

console.log("foo3", foo3);
```

It doesnt seem that complicated I'll continue to try to solve it myself, but for some reason dynamic recursion like this confuses me. How can I modify this deep merge function to support array merging too?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This prevents issues with duplicating circular objects

```js
function isCyclic(obj) {
  var seenObjects = [];

  function detect(obj) {
    if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
      if (seenObjects.indexOf(obj) !== -1) {
        return true;
      }
      seenObjects.push(obj);
      for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && detect(obj[key])) {
          //console.log(obj, 'cycle at ' + key);
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  return detect(obj);
}

function isObject(item) {
  return item && typeof item === 'object' && !Array.isArray(item);
}

function isIterable(item) {
  let type = false;
  if (isObject(item)) type = 'obj';
  else if (Array.isArray(item)) type = 'arr';
  return type;
}

function mergeDeeper(source, target) {
  console.log('merging', source, target);
  let allProps = [];
  let sourceProps;
  let type;
  let targetProps;

  if (isObject(source)) {
    sourceProps = Object.keys(source);
    type = 'obj';
  } else if (Array.isArray(source)) {
    sourceProps = source;
    type = 'arr';
  } else {
    console.log('merged', source, target, 'into', source);
    return source;
  }
  console.log('type', type);

  console.log('sourceProps', sourceProps);

  if (isObject(target)) {
    targetProps = Object.keys(target);
  } else if (Array.isArray(target)) {
    targetProps = target;
  } else {
    throw "target missing"
  }

  console.log('targetProps', targetProps);

  sourceProps.forEach(prop => {
    allProps.push(prop);
  });
  targetProps.forEach(prop => {
    allProps.push(prop);
  });

  allProps = [...new Set(allProps)];

  let merged
  if (type == 'obj') {
    merged = {};
  } else if (type == 'arr') {
    merged = [];
  }

  console.log('allProps', allProps);

  allProps.forEach(prop => {
    if (type == "obj") {
      if (source[prop]) {
        if (isIterable(source[prop])) {
          if (target[prop] !== undefined) merged[prop] = mergeDeeper(source[prop], target[prop])
          else merged[prop] = source[prop]
        } else merged[prop] = source[prop]
      } else {
        if (isIterable(target[prop])) {
          if (source[prop] !== undefined) merged[prop] = mergeDeeper(target[prop], source[prop])
          else merged[prop] = target[prop]
        } else merged[prop] = target[prop]
      }
    } else {
      let iterable = isIterable(prop);
      if (iterable) {
        let filler
        if (iterable == "obj") filler = {};
        else if (iterable == "arr") filler = [];
        merged.push(mergeDeeper(prop, filler))
      } else {
        merged.push(prop)
      }
    }
  })
  console.log('merged', source, target, 'into', merged);
  return merged;
}

let foo1 = {
  bar1: {
    baz1: true,
    baz2: 1,
    baz3: [true, 1, 'true', false, { doodle: "boop" }],
  },
  bar2: ['baz1', 'baz2'],
  bar3: true,
  bar4: 1,
  bar5: 'true',
  bar6: false,
};

let foo2 = {
  bar1: {
    boop: true,
    baz3: ["boop"],
    foo1
  },
  bar2: ['boop'],
  boop: "bar"
};

console.log('foo1', JSON.stringify(foo1, null, 2));

console.log('foo2', JSON.stringify(foo2, null, 2));

let foo3 = mergeDeeper(foo1, foo2);

console.log('foo3', JSON.stringify(foo3, null, 2));
```